# sqlite collate nocase search inside json

Tags: sql, json, sqlite, select, where-clause

I have  a query on country table . It has "data" which is of type json .

```
select country.countryNo,country.population 
from country 
where json_extract(country.data,'$."stateCount"')="23" COLLATE NOCASE ;
```

This fails to give me results where json inside model has Statecount instead of stateCount

Did I used COLLATE NOCASE wrongly ?

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the purpose of `COLLATE NOCASE`. It actually applies to the preceding comparison operator (here, `'='`). So in your query, it makes the comparison of the return value of `json_extract()` against `'23'` case-insensitive - which, as you would agree, does not make a difference.

On the other hand, json keys are case-senstive by nature. If you want to search for json keys that have different cases, then you do need to enumerate them:

```
 where 
    json_extract(country.data,'$.stateCount') = 23
    or json_extract(country.data,'$.StateCount') = 23
```

Side note: if the json value data under the given key is numeric, `json_extract()` gives you a numeric value, that you can directly compare against a number.